# Basic question about group actions and orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group acting on a set $X$, then we know that the set of orbits $O_x$ forms a partition of $X$ and the associated equivalence relation is $x \sim y$ iff $gx=y$ for some $g\in G$.

Suppose $G=S_3$ and $X= \{1,2,3\} \times \{1,2,3\}$, then $G$ acts on $X$ by $\sigma (i,j)= (\sigma (i), \sigma (j))$. But then we have

$$O_{(3,3)}=\{(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)\}$$

$$O_{(1,2)}=\{(1,2),(2,1),(1,3),(3,1),(2,3),(3,2)\}$$.

SO how can $O_x$ forms a partition of $X$? I think i misunderstood something, please helps.

Comment: $O_{(1,2)}$ is not $X$

Comment: #Jack Yoon yes you are right, i have edited it, thanks

Comment: Therefore they partition the set $X$. Maybe you are confused with the definition of 'partition'

Comment: $|X| = 9$, there are exactly two partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The orbits are the pairs formed by picking two columns from the permutations below. Either the two columns are the same or not. If they are the same, there are just three pairs (call this set $S$), if the are different, all possible distinct pairs of $1,2,3$ appear (call this set $D$).
$$\begin{array}{c}
\sigma\\
123\\
132\\
213\\
231\\
312\\
321
\end{array}$$
Since $D \cap S = \emptyset$ and $D \cup S = X$, we see that $D,S$ is a partition of $X$.

Comment: i am confused. Isn't the equivalence classes (which are the orbits in this case) have the same cardinality? but $|O_{(3,3)}|=3, |O_{(1,2)}|=6.$

Comment: No, why would they have the same cardinality? They are not cosets of a group.

Comment: A collection of equivalence classes is exactly a partition.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought equivalence classes have same cardinality like cosets in quotient group. Thanks!

Comment: The cosets are equivalence classes, but the (sub)group structure forces the same cardinality. Group actions are simultaneously simple and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be OK: You have exactly $2$ different equivalence
classes $O_{(3,3)}$ and $O_{(1,2)}$ that form a partition of $X$
:
$$
X=O_{(3,3)}\cup O_{(1,2)}
$$

and 
$$
O_{(3,3)}\cap O_{(1,2)}=\emptyset
$$

and if $x\in X$ then 
$
[x]=O_{(3,3)}
$
or 
$
[x]=O_{(1,2)}
$

so indeed there are no other equivalence classes